# Explain the effects of differences in the velocities of electromagnetic waves to different substances

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light

It's a [GCSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Certificate_of_Secondary_Education) specification point and I cannot find notes or answers on the internet. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The [GCSE (9-1) Gateway Science Physics A: Waves in matter Delivery Guide](https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/289188-waves-in-matter-delivery-guide.pdf) gives this point as:

> P5.3b explain how some effects are related to differences in the velocity of
> electromagnetic waves in different substances

and goes on to discuss

> ... what learners know about visible light: here they may offer knowledge on wavelength and frequency, [...] colour, reflection and refraction [...]
>
> A quick revision of refraction at a glass prism [...] refraction at both concave and convex lenses.
>
> ... relating ray diagrams to real world situations, and move beyond the theory to help [learners] understand light behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

For transverse EM waves entering a more dense material than previous, they slow down and bend towards the normal. The speed of EM waves depends on the DENSITY of the medium they travel through. The more dense the medium, the slower the EM wave travels, the smaller its wavelength gets. Why? Because in $v=f \lambda$, $v$ is directly proportional to $\lambda$. Assuming Frequency is constant, which it is when a wave travels to another medium.